# R: evaluate comma-separated string as an expression

Tags: r, string, parsing, expression, eval

I have a comma-separated string that I want to plug into a function as a comma-separated expression. Specifically, there are various functions that take `...` as a parameter, and I want to have a method for converting comma-separated strings into a list of comma-separated parameters that can be 'injected' into the `...` parameter in a function call. I tried using `parse`  and `eval` as hinted at [on this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-string-to-an-expression-in-r-programming-parse-function/), but I am still failing to get my function to work.

Below you see a reproducible example of what I am trying to do.

**This works just fine**

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
sum(a, b)
```

**If `a` and `b`  are encoded in a string, I can't get them to evaluate in the `sum` function**

This fails because `myString` is of character class, and the function tries to evaluate it as is instead of parsing it into components `a` and `b`.

```
myString <- 'a, b'
sum(myString)
```

**Trying to use `parse` and `eval` also fails**

These give an error about unexpected commas.

```
sum(parse(text = myString))
sum(eval(parse(text = mystring)))
```

Output:

```
Error in parse(text = myString) : <text>:1:2: unexpected ','
1: a,
     ^
```

**What function or set of functions (`fxn`) must I use on `myString` so that `sum`  will correctly evaluate?**

My desired solution will take the following format, where  `fxn` are the functions that must be used on `myString` before the `sum` function:

```
# Acceptable solution format
sum(fxn(myString))

# Alternatively by piping
myString %>%
    fxn %>%
    sum
```

*Update:*

The solution must be generalizable enough to handle if there are more than just two values encoded in `myString`. For example, the solution must also work if:

```
c <- 3
d <- 4
e <- 5
myString2 <- 'c, d, e'

# This:
sum(fxn(myString2))

# Must yield `12`
```

Furthermore, the result should be generalizable enough to work for a variety of functions that take `...` as a parameter, not just `sum`. I selected `sum` for the example for simplicity. However, below is another example of desired behavior:

```
f <- 6
g <- 7
myString3 <- 'f, g'

# This:
prod(fxn(myString3))

# Must yield `42`
```

Comment: this is going to be difficult.  Does `sum` have to be a separate step in the pipeline?  Are you allowed to use `do.call`? Or `purrr::lift`?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `purrr::lift`, so I'd be interested to see how that might be used.    

I'd be okay with a solution relying on `do.call`, as I've started learning how to use it recently, but I haven't come to a clean solution with it (yet).  

If you have a solution where `sum` is not a separate step, then I'd be interested to see, :).

**An important constraint** is that the solution must be generalizable for any number of parameters that would go into `sum` (e.g., if `myString <- 'a, b, c, d'`. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: I should also clarify, the role of `sum` in this example is simply to make a reproducible example. Any function that takes `...` would be suitable. I am looking for the generalizable strategy to convert a comma-separated string into a comma-separated expression that can be 'injected' into a function that takes `...` as a parameter. Again, I'll update the question to reflect this constraint.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, otherwise `sum(eval(parse(text=paste("c(",myString,")"))))` would work

Comment: you might also clarify whether the comma-separated elements will always be single symbols, or whether they might need to be evaluated (e.g. `myString <- 'log(x), y + z, w`)

Comment: Single symbols. Thanks for asking, :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is to use strsplit, then get() each value by sapply().

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
d <- 4
myString <- 'a, b, c, d'

fxn <- function(myString) 
{
  values <- unlist(strsplit(myString, split = ", "))
  sapply(values, function(x){get(x)})
}
sum(fxn(myString))

[1] 10
```

Comment: nice.  I tried something similar with `mget()` but ran into environment trouble.

Comment: Thanks for you commend :)

Comment: Now I have a slight moral dilemma... Your solution works for `sum`, but not for `prod`. The moral dillemma is that you have a solution based on my original question as asked, but as I clarified later, I am actually after a more robust solution that can be generalizable to other functions that take `...` as a parameter, not just `sum`. What is the etiquette here? Should I award you the solution, and then repost my question with this constraint clear from the very beginning? I'm sorry for the confusion, and I thank you for this solution, although it doesn't cover the full breadth of use I hoped

Comment: I think this solution works on general. fxn() return vector of value. try use my my code just fxn(...) (no sum). Also 'prod(fxn(myString))' = 24, means that is works. Sorry if it is still not your point.

Comment: `prod(fxn(myString3))` gives error `Error in prod(fxn(myString3)): invalid 'type' (list) of argument`

Comment: The code works fine for me. May I ask if 'myString3' is not typo?

Comment: Full code, still produces error.
```
f <- 6
g <- 7
myString3 <- 'f, g'
fxn <- function(myString) 
{
  g<- unlist(strsplit(myString, split = ", "))
  sapply(g, function(x){get(x)})
}
prod(fxn(myString3))
```

Comment: That because the the g you assign interfere with local environment edit my "g" to anything unique should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Pete! You were spot on regarding the overlapping variable names. Thanks for pointing out my oversight, and also for providing your robust solution. I've accepted your answer now, :).