# Error in parse(text = expression) : <text>:2:1: unexpected ','

Tags: r, string, parsing, expression, eval

Solutions to prior similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790238/why-is-parsetext-throwing-an-error-when-there-is-a-comma-in-the-text) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675438/r-evaluate-comma-separated-string-as-an-expression) do not work.

```
f_letter <- 'a'
l_letter <- 'c'
sep <- c(':', ',')
to <- 1
and <- 2

expression <- noquote(c(which(letters == f_letter), 
   sep[and], which(letters == l_letter)))
expression

eval(parse(text=expression))
```

> Error in parse(text = expression) : :2:1: unexpected ',' 1: 1 2:
> ,    ^

Expected output:

```
#for sep[and]
1 3

#for sep[to]
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790238/why-is-parsetext-throwing-an-error-when-there-is-a-comma-in-the-text), you could try a similar approach.

First you should use `c` instead of `,` since the first is a function, the latter is not. So you could do something like this:

```
f_letter <- 'a'
l_letter <- 'c'
sep <- c(":", "c")
to <- 1
and <- 2

do.call(sep[to], list( which(letters == f_letter), which(letters == l_letter) ))
[1] 1 2 3


do.call(sep[and], list( which(letters == f_letter), which(letters == l_letter) ))
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: instead of the comma there should be a `c`: `c(1L, 3L)`. If you have a comma there `,(1L, 3L)` you should correct your previous code.

Comment: Sometimes `do.call(sep[and], list( which(letters == f_letter), which(letters == l_letter) )) returns: Error in ,(1L, 3L) : could not find function ","`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a way to use comma directly in your answer?

Comment: I don't think I can answer without more context. In Ricardo's answer you can use a comma in your code but you're still calling the function `c()` every time regardless of sep: `c(1:3)` or `c(1,3)`. You can use his answer or if you want to avoid the parse function you can try to update your question specifying why you need to use the comma and the intermediary step you need. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works as expected. I appreciate greatly. I compared both solutions in terms of speed and memory allocation. `do.call()` appears to be less demanding compared to `eval(parse(noquote(paste0()))`, despite the inconvenience regarding comma, which remains unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

`nonquote` adds spaces between the strings, and `1 : 3` is non syntactic. `1,3` is also wrong, what you want is `c(1,3)`. We can make those adjustments using `paste0()`:

```
expression <- noquote(paste0('c(', which(letters == f_letter), 
                        sep[and], which(letters == l_letter), ')'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works as expected. I appreciate greatly. I compared both solutions in terms of speed and memory allocation. `do.call()` appears to be less demanding compared to `eval(parse(noquote(paste0()))`, despite the inconvenience regarding comma, which remains unresolved.